# How to prove the convergence of following series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let ($a_n$)  be a sequence of positive terms such that $\sum_ {n=1}^{\infty} n^2 a_{n}^2 \lt \infty$ prove that $\sum_ {n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}\lt \infty$

I start with $n^2 a_{n}^2 \to 0 $ as $n \to \infty$

$\implies  \frac{a_{n}^2}{\frac{1}{n^2}} \to 0 $ as $n \to \infty$

$\implies \sum_ {n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} \lt \infty$

But this doesn't give the convergence of $\sum_ {n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean $<\infty$ instead of $\le\infty$ everywhere?

Comment: If you mean $<\infty$, try Cauchy-Schwarz with $a_n = \frac 1n\cdot (na_n)$.

Comment: Yes... I mean < previously it was a typo. Sorry for make you confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n^2a_n\le 1$, then $a_n = \frac 1{n^2}(n^2a_n)\le\frac 1{n^2}$.

If $n^2a_n>1$, then $a_n = \frac 1{n^2a_n}n^2a_n^2\le n^2a_n^2$.

So,
$$
\sum_na_n\,\le\,\sum_n\frac 1{n^2} + \sum_n n^2a_n^2\,<\,\infty.
$$

Comment: You may also avoid splitting cases and just invoke $$ a_n=\text{GM}(n^2 a_n^2,1/n^2)\leq \text{AM}(n^2 a_n^2,1/n^2)=\frac{1}{2}\left(n^2 a_n^2+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ leading to $\sum a_n \leq \frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{1}{2}\sum n^2 a_n$.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know an inequality who says that: if $(x_{n})$ and $(y_{n})$ are sequences such that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{|x_{n}|^{2}} < \infty$ and $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{|y_{n}|^{2}} < \infty$ then $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{|y_{n}x_{n}|} < \infty$? Usually this goes with the name Holder's inequality or Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Take $y_{n} = \frac{1}{n}$ and $x_{n} = na_{n}$ and you will have: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^{2}}} < \infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n^{2}a_{n}^{2}} < \infty$ (it's your hypothesis), then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n}(na_{n})} < \infty$

Comment: That's already in the comments, but ok...