# Given that $a_n>0,$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2 a_n^2$ is convergent, show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

### This is a question from a competitive examination.

Given that $a_n>0,$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2 a_n^2$ is convergent.

Check if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent.

My attempt:
I tried to find some counterexample to show that this series need not be convergent, but I am unable to find any. So I feel that this is true.

I also tried Holder's inequality to show this but it was of no use. Any help or ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/640326, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3399066 – it is an immediate application of Cauchy-Schwarz to $\sum \frac 1n \cdot (n a_n)$

Answer (score 0):

This is TRUE by Using A.M - G.M Inequality.
Given that, $\sum n^2a_n^2$ is cgt & we know $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ is cgt by $p-$series test.
Now, By A.M-G.M Inequality,We get,
$\frac{(n^2a_n^2+\frac{1}{n^2})}{2}≥a_n$(given $a_n>0$)

Now, By Using comparison test,
$\sum a_n$ is convergent.